# Scheduling code after date input from user in r

Tags: r, shiny

I am able to take input dates from the user and but can't make it wait to execute after entering the dates.
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(quantmod)

```
# Define UI for application that draws a bar graph
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("My Plot"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         textInput("text", "Enter company name:", width = NULL,
                   placeholder = "comp.name"),
         dateRangeInput("dates", h3(strong("Date Range")), 
                        start = "2001-01-01", end = Sys.Date(),
                        min = "0000-01-01", max = Sys.Date(),
                        format = "dd-mm-yy", separator = strong("to"),
                        autoclose = TRUE),
                        submitButton(text = "submit")),

      # Show a plot
      mainPanel( h1(strong(textOutput("Company"))),
      tableOutput("MRF"),
      plotOutput("finally")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

      output$MRF <- renderTable({
        tyu2 <- getSymbols(input$text , src = "yahoo", verbose = TRUE,
        from = min(input$date) , to = max(input$date), auto.assign = FALSE)})
      output$finally <- renderPlot({ggplot(data = tyu2 , aes(x= x ,y=tyu))+
          geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue")+
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
          xlab("Dates")+ ylab(comp.name)})
   }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The dates must be going in as infinity which is the default case when the dates are not being read. I am not understanding what is wrong. Could anybody help me out. Thank you

Comment: I think this is a typo. You give your date input the ID `"dates"` but then try to use `input$date`, it should be `input$dates`.

Comment: thank you very much